# how make in django after one time login stay login when ever user log out

Tags: python, html, django

after one time login it automaticely logout next runserver time, can i prevent ?

it is possiable example facebook ,youtube other web page . in my case when start of my Django Project(Runserver) and when I logging with authenticate data and it is successful to login , after  complete work and I close the django run server then it is automatically logout dot but I want to the previous login account is tail login if the user want to log out in that case it is logout but other case it is still again